# "I will just " vs. "I will "

Tags: meaning

What's the difference between "I will just" and "I will".

Examples:

- I will just order it.

  I will order it.

Do they have the same meaning?

Answer (score 3):

"[Just](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/just)" is a word with many meanings.  In some cases, like the word "actually", it may add no real value to a sentence.

In your example, it's hard to tell.  It could mean "simply", thus having a meaning like

"I can't be bothered thinking about it any more - I'm simply going to order it."

It could also mean "I'm going to order it now, then I'll do the other thing you wanted me to do."

There could be other possibilities too.  Without more context it's just guesswork.